# Android stop sprite from changing subimages when staying

Tags: java, android

Currently my sprite animates like it was in movement not only when is in movement but also when it stays in one place. Of course I want to stay still without animation when it stays in one place. How to solve that?

```
public abstract class GameMovingObject {
    
    private static final int ROW_TOP_TO_BOTTOM = 0;
    private static final int ROW_RIGHT_TO_LEFT = 1;
    private static final int ROW_LEFT_TO_RIGHT = 2;
    private static final int ROW_BOTTOM_TO_TOP = 3;
    
    public boolean justSeen=true;
    protected Bitmap image;
    private final int rowCount, colCount;
    protected final int WIDTH, HEIGHT;
    private final int width, height;
    private int x;
    public int getX() { return this.x; }
    public void setX(int x) { this.x = x; }
    private int y;
    public int getY() { return this.y; }
    public void setY(int y) { this.y = y; }
    
    // Row index of Image are being used.
    private int rowUsing = ROW_LEFT_TO_RIGHT;
    
    private int colUsing;
    
    private Bitmap[] leftToRights;
    private Bitmap[] rightToLefts;
    private Bitmap[] topToBottoms;
    private Bitmap[] bottomToTops;
    
    // Velocity of game character (pixel/millisecond)
    public float velocity = 0.15f;
    
    public int getMovingVectorX() {
        return movingVectorX;
    }
    public int getMovingVectorY() {
        return movingVectorY;
    }
    
    public int movingVectorX = 0;
    public int movingVectorY = 0;
    
    public long lastDrawNanoTime =-1;
    
    public GameSurface gs;
    
    public GameMovingObject(GameSurface gs, Bitmap image, int rowCount, int colCount, int x, int y) {
    
        this.gs = gs;
    
        this.image = image;
        this.rowCount = rowCount;
        this.colCount = colCount;
    
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    
        this.WIDTH = image.getWidth();
        this.HEIGHT = image.getHeight();
    
        this.width = this.WIDTH / colCount;
        this.height = this.HEIGHT / rowCount;
    
        this.topToBottoms = new Bitmap[colCount]; // 3
        this.rightToLefts = new Bitmap[colCount]; // 3
        this.leftToRights = new Bitmap[colCount]; // 3
        this.bottomToTops = new Bitmap[colCount]; // 3
    
        for(int col = 0; col< this.colCount; col++ ) {
            this.topToBottoms[col] = this.createSubImageAt(ROW_TOP_TO_BOTTOM, col);
            this.rightToLefts[col]  = this.createSubImageAt(ROW_RIGHT_TO_LEFT, col);
            this.leftToRights[col] = this.createSubImageAt(ROW_LEFT_TO_RIGHT, col);
            this.bottomToTops[col]  = this.createSubImageAt(ROW_BOTTOM_TO_TOP, col);
        }
    }
    
    public Bitmap[] getMoveBitmaps()  {
        switch (rowUsing)  {
            case ROW_BOTTOM_TO_TOP:
                return  this.bottomToTops;
            case ROW_LEFT_TO_RIGHT:
                return this.leftToRights;
            case ROW_RIGHT_TO_LEFT:
                return this.rightToLefts;
            case ROW_TOP_TO_BOTTOM:
                return this.topToBottoms;
            default:
                return null;
        }
    }
    
    public void setMovingVector(int movingVectorX, int movingVectorY)  {
        this.movingVectorX= movingVectorX;
        this.movingVectorY = movingVectorY;
    }
    
    public Bitmap getCurrentMoveBitmap()  {
        Bitmap[] bitmaps = this.getMoveBitmaps();
        return bitmaps[this.colUsing];
    }
    
    public void draw(Canvas canvas)  {
        Bitmap bitmap = this.getCurrentMoveBitmap();
        canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap,x, y, null);
        // Last draw time.
        this.lastDrawNanoTime= System.nanoTime();
    }

    public void update()  {
        this.colUsing++;
        if(colUsing >= this.colCount)  {
            this.colUsing =0;
        }
        // Current time in nanoseconds
        long now = System.nanoTime();
    
        // Never once did draw.
        if(lastDrawNanoTime==-1) {
            lastDrawNanoTime= now;
        }
        // Change nanoseconds to milliseconds (1 nanosecond = 1000000 milliseconds).
        int deltaTime = (int) ((now - lastDrawNanoTime)/   777777 );
    
        // Distance moves
        float distance = velocity * deltaTime;
    
        double movingVectorLength = Math.sqrt(movingVectorX* movingVectorX + movingVectorY*movingVectorY);
    
        // Calculate the new position of the game character.
        this.x = x +  (int)(distance* movingVectorX / movingVectorLength);
        this.y = y +  (int)(distance* movingVectorY / movingVectorLength);
    
        // When the game's character touches the edge of the screen, then change direction
    
        if(this.x < 0 ) {
            this.x = 0;
            this.movingVectorX = - this.movingVectorX;
        } else if(this.x > this.gs.getWidth() -width) {
            this.x= this.gs.getWidth()-width;
            this.movingVectorX = - this.movingVectorX;
        }
    
        if(this.y < 0 ) {
            this.y = 0;
            this.movingVectorY = - this.movingVectorY;
        }
    
        // rowUsing (obraca postać)
        if( movingVectorX > 0 ){
            if(movingVectorY > 0 && Math.abs(movingVectorX) < Math.abs(movingVectorY)) {
                this.rowUsing = ROW_TOP_TO_BOTTOM;
            }
            else if(movingVectorY < 0 && Math.abs(movingVectorX) < Math.abs(movingVectorY)) {
                this.rowUsing = ROW_BOTTOM_TO_TOP;
            }
            else  {
                this.rowUsing = ROW_LEFT_TO_RIGHT;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if(movingVectorY > 0 && Math.abs(movingVectorX) < Math.abs(movingVectorY)) {
                this.rowUsing = ROW_TOP_TO_BOTTOM;
            }
            else if(movingVectorY < 0 && Math.abs(movingVectorX) < Math.abs(movingVectorY)) {
                this.rowUsing = ROW_BOTTOM_TO_TOP;
            }
            else if(movingVectorX!=0 || movingVectorY!=0)  {
                this.rowUsing = ROW_RIGHT_TO_LEFT;
            }
        }
    }
    
    protected Bitmap createSubImageAt(int row, int col) {
        // createBitmap(bitmap, x, y, width, height).
        Bitmap subImage = Bitmap.createBitmap(image, col * width, row * height, width, height);
        return subImage;
    }
    
    public int getHeight() {
        return height;
    }
    
    public int getWidth() {
        return width;
    }
```

I was trying to add

```
if(movingVectorY!=0) this.topToBottoms[col] = this.createSubImageAt(ROW_TOP_TO_BOTTOM, col);
else this.topToBottoms[1] = this.createSubImageAt(ROW_TOP_TO_BOTTOM, 1);
```

but then sprite blinks and is without animation even when moving. I think I added everything you need to know. It there is anything you want me to add just ask me. Thank you in advance.